# Вызов нового окна.

Tags: java, swing

Хочу сделать подобие меню, по клику на кнопку старое окно должно исчезать, а вместо него появляться новое. Поясните, пожалуйста, почему данный код не работает?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Menu implements ActionListener{

    JFrame menu;
    JFrame window;
    JButton newWindow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame menu;
        Menu setVisible = new Menu();
        setVisible.go();

    }

    public void go() {
        menu = new JFrame();
        newWindow = new JButton("new Window");
        menu.setVisible(true);
        menu.setSize(500, 600);

        menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        menu.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, newWindow);
        newWindow.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        menu.setVisible(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(500, 600);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Поясните, пожалуйста, почему данный код не работает?

В методе `actionPerformed(...)` Вы пытаетесь вызывать методы объекта `window`, который еще не был создан, соответственно и получаете `NullPointerException`, так как по-умолчанию объектные поля класса инициализируются значением `null`.

Необходимо сначала создать объект, а уже потом вызывать его методы:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    menu.setVisible(false);
    window = new JFrame();
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.setSize(500, 600);
}
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ.